# Get Final output from UDK

Tags: udk, unreal

( sorry for my bad english in advance :D )

I'm trying to get a .exe setup output, from my UDK !( with my own maps and scripts which I made within MyGame)
I tried UnrealFrontEnd! But It made a setup , that after installation I can see my .udk maps, my packages and etc.
But It's not a real output that I can show to my customers. I don't want, other can use my resources !

So... How can I get a binary-like output from UDK as a real Game-Output ? ( like what we see in all commercial games )
Is there any option in frontend that I missed ?

Comment: I think you need to get license for your game or something and then it will be converted into a usual pc game.

Comment: Can you explain ? or Give a link that give more detail about "How?" ? I didn't find any information in UDK website about that.

Comment: Sorry ! I notice that my question is a little wrong and I write it in a wrong way :D Anyway I found my Answer at [Here](http://www.hourences.com/an-entire-simple-udk-game/). Thanks anyway

Comment: So what is ur real question. Coz in the link that you have given in above comment talks about "Tutorials – UE3 A simple UDK Game". If there is anything that you have learnt different there would u like to share it

Comment: in fact, My main Problem was that, my output was a empty map and I didn't know how to connect it with my unreal Script code. And I found my answer in "View–>World Properties->Game Type" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some time to setup, but afterward building new version is pretty straightforward.

First, update config file UDKGame\Config\DefaultEngine.ini or DefaultEngineUDK.ini.

There are 4 sections you need to update: [Engine.ScriptPackages], [UnrealEd.EditorEngine], [Engine.StartupPackages] and [Engine.PackagesToAlwaysCook].

**[Engine.ScriptPackages]**
Add here lines for all new script packages like this:

```
[Engine.ScriptPackages]
+NonNativePackages=UTGame
+NonNativePackages=UTGameContent
+NonNativePackages=NewScriptPackage
```

If you do not use classes from UTGame and UTGameContent then it`s safe to remove them from config.

**[UnrealEd.EditorEngine]**
You need to add there lines for script packages. That settings is used to include scripts for compiling step, so there are high chances that settings are already done.

**[Engine.StartupPackages]**
Add lines for content packages at this section. You need to add here only packages that need to be loaded all time, e.g script packages, font packages. Also include here packages resources from are referenced dynamicaly via **DynamicLoadObject()** method. Otherwise such packages will not be cooked.

**[Engine.PackagesToAlwaysCook]**
You need to add here packages that are not referenced from other packages but still need to be distributed, e.g. entry level map.

After this setup fire up UDK Frontend and run build cycle - recompile, cook, package. After this you will get installer with cooked game. That game only has executables, configs, maps, separate texture file and Startup.upk package with all other resources.

Comment: You're right and also [here](http://udkc.info/index.php?title=Tutorials:Beginning_your_game) is a overview of all steps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the discussion about the license of ue3 and how it works, if you are still not clear about how you will make a standalone game using udk then comment to my answer.

http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/718894-What-kind-of-licensing-is-required-to-get-access-to-the-udk-source-code?s=6cdd2818f53ab93ac44eb32b52a9db6f

Check out this reply to above question by one of the users in the epicgames forum.

http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/718894-What-kind-of-licensing-is-required-to-get-access-to-the-udk-source-code?p=27145813&viewfull=1#post27145813